# Why does N2263 view "wildcard" or "escape-hatch" provenance as problematical?

Tags: c, pointers, strict-aliasing

Reading through standard proposal document "n2263: Clarifying Pointer Provenance v4" (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2263.htm#provenance-escape-hatches-for-io-and-inter-object-arithmetic---and-the-problem-with-wildcards), the authors seem to think that it would be impractical to simply say that pointers produced by means the compiler doesn't understand (e.g. performing unusual integer computations and converting the result to a pointer, or reading a `volatile` address that might be attached to hardware that does pointer arithmetic) may alias any object whose address has been exposed to the outside world.

Although regarding the results of integer-to-pointer casts or reads of pointers from volatile addresses as having "unknowable" provenance might occasionally impede optimizations that would otherwise be useful, such operations would seem to occur primarily in situations where pointers could in fact identify things a compiler would have no *particular* reason to "expect".  While there are some cases where a compiler would benefit from knowing that a particular object won't be aliased *despite* its address having been exposed to the outside world, adding general means of providing such information (e.g. a parameter qualifier to indicate that no pointer derived from that parameter will be used after the function returns) would be more useful than worrying about only in the context of "wildcard" or "escape hatch" pointers.

Most compilers, including essentially all compilers that are suitable for systems programming, will have some means of invoking functions whose precise behavior cannot be known to the compiler or linker.  They will consequently need some means of handling the possibility that pointers received from such functions might be derived from any address that has ever been exposed to the outside world (either by being passed as an argument to an outside function, or being stored in a globally-accessible object when an outside function is called).  What would be problematical about treating pointers produced by other "escape hatches" in the same fashion?  What practical benefits could be obtained by treating them otherwise?